# Batch Move file to folder starting with same number

Tags: batch-file, copy

We have a lot of backup config files, we need to save on a drive.
The file is `123456_name.cfg` or `12345_name.cfg`
This may vary, but always starting with a number of 5-6 int.

I'm tring to make a batch file which checks the number in front of the name before the "_",
if a folder is also starting with the same number, copy the file to it,
if folder doesn't exist, create a folder ID Name and copy file to it.
Here is what i already test:

```
    @echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.cfg') do (
set "filename1=%%~i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder1=!filename1:~0,5!"
mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
move "!filename1!" "!folder1!" >nul
endlocal
)
```

The problem is that i have files starting with 5 numbers or 6 Numbers.
Actually it create a Folder only with the 5 first numbers not the file full name. 
If it can only check the id before the "_"

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts by providing a [mcve]! Read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: To ensure that you only get `.cfg` files beginning with five or six digits followed by an underscore, ignoring those beginning with any other number of digits you could use something a scary as this inside the parentheses of a `For /F` loop: `'Dir /B/A-D ?????_*.cfg ??????_*.cfg^|FindStr /I "\\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_.*\.cfg\> \\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_.*\.cfg\>"'`.

Answer (score 0):

split the string at the `_`:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for %%a in (12345 123456 987 987654321) do break>%%a_name.cfg

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.cfg') do (
  for /f "delims=_" %%j in ("%%~ni") do (
    mkdir "%%j" 2>nul
    move "%%i" "%%j"
  )
)
```

the first `for %%a` is just to generate some test files.
the third `for` (`%%j`) splits the filename (`%%~ni`) and takes the first part before the (first) `_`
So in `move "%%i" "%%j"`, `%%i` is the full drive:\path\filename and `%%j` is just the number

Comment: This create a folder withe the ID ant put the file in, that's already great. I have already some folders 123456_name, how can i put the file starting by 123456 in the folder starting by 123456 and if folder doesn't exist create it with the file name.

Comment: so if you have a file like `56425_beta.cfg` and a folder `56425_alpha` exists, you want to move `56425_beta.cfg` to `56425_alpha` and if there is no such folder, you want to create a `56425_beta`?

Comment: yes exact, because we already have some folders, but some of them didn't have exactly the same name as the file.

Comment: But the file name may be 56425_beta of 200787_beta ( 5 or 6 digits)